# How to remove windows user account using C#

Tags: c#, windows

How to remove windows user account using C#?

Answer (score 12):

[Clause Thomsen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/642487/17768086) was close, you need to pass the `DirectoryEntry.Remove` method a `DirectoryEntry` parameter instead of a string, like:

```
DirectoryEntry localDirectory = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName.ToString());
DirectoryEntries users = localDirectory.Children;
DirectoryEntry user = users.Find("userName");
users.Remove(user);
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do the trick(not tested):

```
DirectoryEntry localMachine = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" +  Environment.MachineName);

DirectoryEntries entries = localMachine.Children;
DirectoryEntry user = entries.Remove("User");
entries.CommitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement in .NET 3.5:-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924557.aspx

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

namespace AdministratorsGroupSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
            GroupPrincipal grpp = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);
            UserPrincipal usrp = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

            PrincipalSearcher ps_usr = new PrincipalSearcher(usrp);
            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> fr_usr = ps_usr.FindAll();

            PrincipalSearcher ps_grp = new PrincipalSearcher(grpp);
            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> fr_grp = ps_grp.FindAll();

            foreach (var usr in fr_usr)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Name:{usr.Name} SID:{usr.Sid} Desc:{usr.Description}");
                Console.WriteLine("\t Groups:");
                foreach (var grp in usr.GetGroups())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + $"Name:{grp.Name} SID:{grp.Sid} Desc:{grp.Description}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            foreach (var grp in fr_grp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{grp.Name} {grp.Description}");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private void Delete(string userName)
        {
            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
            UserPrincipal usrp = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
            usrp.Name = userName;
            PrincipalSearcher ps_usr = new PrincipalSearcher(usrp);
            var user = ps_usr.FindOne();
            user.Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This example will only list the user accounts on the PC, and what groups they belong to, not delete them, as asked in the original question.

Comment: you can find the target user by ```FindOne()```  ，and use the ```Delete``` method .

Comment: this method can be used for domain users too.